# Move to top position of div using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have developed phonegap android app using javascript.I need to move to the top of div in button click using javascript or jquery.How to do this.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
$('#toTop').click(function() 
{
$('#wrapper').animate({ scrollTop: 0 },200);
});

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign [**`$yourElement.offset().top`**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to `scrollTop` property.

```
$('#toTop').click(function() {
    var wrapper$ = $('#wrapper');
    $(window).animate({
        scrollTop: wrapper$.offset().top
    }, 200);
});

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

I've made a [**code example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/prKLH/), you can play with it.